# Electron: Is it possible to retrieve the date and time that a file last accessed

Tags: windows, macos, electron, file-access

For those of you that use Electron to build desktop apps. Is it possible to retrieve the last access time of executable files on Windows or Mac and how is this done? In C++ one can use the 
    GetFileTime 
function, how can someone do this in an Electron app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron allows use of the Node API meaning the best way to access the file system is to use `fs`. In particular, the `fs.Stats` class described here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

You can use `fs.stat` to get the `fs.Stats` object for the file you want

```
fs.stat("path/to/file.exe", (err, stats) => someFunction(err, stats));
```

Where `someFunction` checks the returned `fs.Stats` object for the relevant data. The API link above says that the `atime`, `mtime`, `ctime`, and `birthtime` properties of the `stats` object representing access time, modified time, changed time, and creation time respectively.